# How to manage overlaying polygons and empty space inside a map?

Tags: qgis, geopandas

I have a map of provinces, but the file is not so good. there are a lot of white space and overlapping provinces. I don't care about the correctness of the map. I need to somehow deal with the overlapping issue and then fill the white space.
for the overlapping again I just need to keep one province and clip the other( the precision of the map is not important).
for the white space, one province could be chosen to fill up. no matter which.
Do you have any idea to handle these two problems?

[image]

Comment: Please, decide between `geopandas` or `qgis`

Comment: @Taras I'm a user of both

Comment: If it's GeoPandas that you choose please include a code attempt.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please decide which of the GIS products mentioned you want to ask about.  By asking about more than one you are effectively asking multiple questions which goes against the [Tour]. You should then describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.